# How to grab a specific field from a datatable created by a stored procedure? (ASP.NET 3.5/C#)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have four tables created by a stored procedure.  I've assigned the tables to four DataTables in my code.

```
DataTable dtAtt = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dtWav = ds.Tables[1];
DataTable dtOrg = ds.Tables[2];
DataTable dtMain = ds.Tables[3];
```

In dtOrg the primary key is OrgMainId.  I need to grab the Name field from dtOrg where OrgMainId = some value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Select` command (code not tested) -

```
string Name;
DataRow[] result = dtOrg.Select("OrgMainId = 'some value'");
foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
  Name = row["name"];
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

Comment: @todd - excellent, I'm pleased it helped. I'd really appreciate it if you could accept the answer if it has helped. Thanks :)